# Can iterator's `value_type` be `const`?

Tags: c++, iterator

I was surprised when I examine the following `std::` code:

```
template<typename _Tp>
struct iterator_traits<const _Tp*>
{
    typedef _Tp                         value_type;
    typedef const _Tp*                  pointer;
    typedef const _Tp&                  reference;
    .....
};
```

So, `value_type` is never `const` if iterator is a `const` pointer. Why?

Is it valid if a non-pointer iterator has its `value_type` as a `const` type?

Comment: A [`const_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) has a `const` value_type.  And a `std::vector<int const>` will have `iterator` to a `const` value_type.

Comment: If "because the standard says so" is not an acceptable answer, you might want to re-write your question to be based on specs instead of on one implementation of the specs. You could use [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits#const_T.2A_specialization_member_types) as a reference, as the table there shows that this is by intent. (It also shows that this particular specialization is removed in C++20, but that appears to be because it was folded into the not-explicitly-const pointer specialization.)

Comment: @Eljay *A const_iterator has a const `value_type`.* - [No](https://godbolt.org/z/K4jP9EnzK). *And a `std::vector<int const>` will have iterator to a const `value_type`.* - It [won't compile](https://godbolt.org/z/94v33qeMn).

Comment: *`value_type` is never `const` if iterator is a `const` pointer. Why?* - When you do `Iterator::value_type val = *iterator;` there is no good reason to make `val` constant - it's a *copy* and you should be able to do with that copy anything you want. That's not the case for pointers and references - `const`-correctness has to be ensured.